# Input box time in html ie

Tags: html, css, html-input

I want to get a 'time' input box (that sows the arrows to increase/decrease time). The following code works in chrome/mozilla but it doesnt in internet explorer :

```
    <label for="moduleStart">Hours from:</label>
    <input type="time" name="moduleStart" class="dateFormat"/>
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What's that second `input` doing there?

Comment: [The time input is HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp) meaning it wont work in IE and other browsers without HTML5 support. But it should in IE9. Your code above has an error in it as Eric has mentioned above. Remove that second "input" before `type="time"`.

Comment: Actually, [IE9 doesn't support `type="time"`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many element types are new in HTML5 thus not supported by older browsers. You could use a **polyfill** for **non HTML5 browsers**.

In this case one like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/598365/html5forms/html5forms.html

> The objective is to allow authors **to use most HTML5 control types** and
>   attributes **even in browsers which do not yet support all these new
>   HTML5 features**. Some of these features are only implemented in the
>   latest version of Opera and partially in Webkit based browsers. To
>   achieve this we need the ability to recognize and handle correct
>   validation for these new types and be able to set:

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer does not support this input type.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML5 Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/) to support HTML5 new input types in browsers that don't support new inputs

From Docs:

> These types can enable native datepickers, colorpickers, URL
>   validation, and so on. If a browser doesn’t support a given type, it
>   will be rendered as a text field. Modernizr cannot detect that date
>   inputs create a datepicker, the color input create a colorpicker, and
>   so on—it will detect that the input values are sanitized based on the
>   spec. In the case of WebKit, we have received confirmation that
>   sanitization will not be added without the UI widgets being in place.